# Visual Studio claims that Python 3.12 is "old version". Rants that NuGet package manager may not work due to "security restrictions"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip, nuget-package

After a clean install on a new windows installation, Visual Studio Community 2022's NuGet package manager, when Python 12 is selected, claims that "Due to new security restrictions, installing from the internet may not work on this version of Python"

[image: screenshot please moderator convert to image]

It links to [this MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments-window-tab-reference?view=vs-2022#security-restrictions-with-older-versions-of-python)

which says:

> The reason for the warning is that with these **older versions of Python** [?], pip install doesn't contain support for the Transport Security Layer (TLS) 1.2, which is required for downloading packages from the package source, pypi.org. Custom Python builds may support TLS 1.2 in which case pip install might work.
>
> It may be possible to download the appropriate get-pip.py for a package from bootstrap.pypa.io, manually download a package from pypi.org, and then install the package from that local copy.
>
> The recommendation, however, is to simply upgrade to a recent version of Python, in which case the warning does not appear.

of course, [bootstrap.pypa.io](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/) only has stuff for old versions of python

What could be the cause? MS bug? Any solution?

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information - do you have a question?